# @Until annotation in Gson not working as expected

Tags: java, json, gson

As per my understanding of [@Until](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Until.html) annotation defined in the docs, it supports all version until the version **included** in the annotation.

**Docs:**

```
 public class User {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   @Until(1.1) private String emailAddress;
   @Until(1.1) private String password;
 }
```

> if you created Gson with Gson gson = new
>   GsonBuilder().setVersion(1.2).create() then the toJson() and
>   fromJson() methods of Gson will exclude the emailAddress and password
>   fields from the example above, because the version number passed to
>   the GsonBuilder, 1.2, exceeds the version number set on the Until
>   annotation, 1.1, for those fields.

So if my gson was built with version 1.1 it should display all 4 fields of the class. However this is not the case.

**My Class**:

```
class TestData {
    private String firstName;

    @Since(1.1)
    private String middleName;

    @Until(1.1)
    private String lastName;
}
```

**Test Code:**

```
TestData testData = new TestData();
testData.setFirstName("first");
testData.setMiddleName("middle");
testData.setLastName("last");
Gson versionGson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().setVersion(1.1).create();
System.out.println(versionGson.toJson(testData));
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "firstName": "first",
  "middleName": "middle"
}
```

`lastName` is missing in output even though the annotation value matches the Gson's version.

Further debugging I found [this](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/Excluder.java#L242) below gson code, which was causing this behavior. Clearly, as per code even though my annotation version matches the version passed to Gson its still considered Invalid.

```
private boolean isValidUntil(Until annotation) {
    if (annotation != null) {
      double annotationVersion = annotation.value();
      if (annotationVersion <= version) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Is the Doc, code or my understanding wrong?

Comment: Where is th `someName` field?

Comment: @CKing Its not there. I removed unnecessary fields from the POJO while pasting, edited the question with the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/annotations/Until.html) states

> An annotation that indicates the version number until a member or a
>   type should be present. Basically, **if `Gson` is created with a version
>   number that exceeds the value stored in the `Until` annotation then the
>   field will be ignored from the JSON output.**

but the [code](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/c935f89b23c69e7c9d6d98df87f81635b3eb3700/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/Excluder.java#L245) returns "invalid" if the version exceeds **or is equal to** the version you specify in `@Until`.

This seems like a bug in the code to me (if you assume the API specification is the source of truth). I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1007) to track this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue in logic, but it is an issue with Javadoc.

The reason I think that is because `@Until` should take a value that is exclusive. That means `@Until(6)` should give values for all versions less than `6`. Otherwise, if there are any hot-fix versions.

For example, If I use `@Until(5.5)` and I expect that it should work only until `5.x` versions. and I have a bug fix and made the version as `5.6` then my whole logic will fail.